# UITable View Items Sometimes Disappear When Selected (Depending On Screen Size)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating a tabbed app with 3 separate view controllers(2 regular views, 1 table view) using Swift 5 and Xcode 11. Inside my 3rd view(which is the one with the table view), and inside of my UITableViewCells, there is 1 button, colored red. I have tested my program on 2 of my testing devices, one with a larger screen, and the other a small, iPhone 5s screen, and here are the results I got:

iPhone with larger screen(iPhone 6 Plus):
All works fine, even if I select the UITableViewCell, the items inside won't disappear

iPhone 5s:
If I don't select the UITableViewCell, all will be fine:
[image]
But If I do select the UITableViewCell, the items inside will disappear:
[image]

This is my uitableviewcontroller:

```swift
import UIKit

@objcMembers class CustomViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tag = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // 3
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tag = tag + 1

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "themeCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell



        /////////
        let cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))
        cellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.addSubview(cellButton)
        cell.accessoryView = cellButton
        cellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        cellButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cellButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        cellButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        cellButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

        cell.img.image = UIImage(named: SingletonViewController.themes[indexPath.row])
        cell.accessoryView = cellButton
        cellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.backBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellButton.tag = tag


        return cell
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but why do you continuously increment `tag`? And why is the `backgroundColor` of the button set twice and the button is assigned to the `accessoryView` twice?. And why is the button additionally added as subview of the cell? And why even multiple times each time the cell is reused? OK the last *why* is irrelevant if `numberOfRows` remains 1.

Comment: @vadian 1. I'm using tag to mark which button I made(haven't used it yet) 2. I was going to make two buttons, but is not finished with it 3/4. I will reuse the cell(but not yet, will do that later)

Comment: Rather than an extra property use the `row` of the index path as `tag`. With your way you won't be able to identify the cell. And you don't need to add the button as subview if it's used as accessory view. I would design the button(s) in Interface Builder anyway.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the suggestion, that helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this code of line

```
cell.accessoryView = cellButton
```

Either add button as subview OR set it as accessory view.

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable the table view from being able to be selected, by adding this to your second 'tableView' function:

```swift
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
```